# Extract four (von Neumann) neighbors of a matrix entry

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix

Assume I have a $m\times n$ matrix and I would like to extract four neighbors of randomly selected entry of a matrix. I have handled if location is not on the boundary. Any suggestion how to handle it if entry is on the boundary or handle it all in once? Thanks.

Here is an example.

```
SeedRandom[123];
{n, m} = {4, 6};
mat = RandomInteger[{1, 5}, {n, m}];
MatrixForm@mat
```

$\text{mat}= \left(    \begin{array}{cccccc}
 4 & 2 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\
 4 & 2 & 2 & 5 & 1 & 2 \\
 5 & 4 & 3 & 3 & 5 & 5 \\
 3 & 5 & 2 & 2 & 5 & 3 \\
\end{array}    \right)$

```
loc = {RandomInteger[{2, n - 1}], RandomInteger[{2, m - 1}]}
fourNeighbor = (Extract[mat, # + loc] &) /@ {{0, -1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {1, 0}}
```

**Edit:**

Here is Moore Neighbors

```
nf = Nearest[Tuples@Range@Dimensions@mat -> Flatten[mat], 
   DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance];

neighbors[pt_] := nf[pt, {All, 1}][[1 ;;]]
```

Or

```
   mooreNeighborPositions =  AdjacencyList[NearestNeighborGraph[Tuples@Range@Dimensions@#,
 DistanceFunction -> ChessboardDistance], #2] &; 

 mooreNeighbors = Extract[#, mooreNeighborPositions@##] &;  mooreNeighbors[mat, {1, 1}]
```

Comment: How do you want to handle boundary cases?  Wrap around (periodic) or include <4 neighbors or ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use [`Nearest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest) for this.

```
nf = Nearest[Tuples @ Range @ Dimensions @ mat -> Flatten[mat]];

neighbors[pt_] := nf[pt, {All, 1}][[2;;]]
```

Some examples:

```
neighbors[{3, 3}]
neighbors[{1, 1}]
neighbors[{4, 6}]
```

> {2, 4, 3, 2}
>
> {2, 4}
>
> {5, 5}

Comment: something is wrong: {2,4} is not a neighbor to {1,1}...

Comment: ...sorry my fault! Every thing is ok!

Answer (score 8):

```
vNNeighborPositions = AdjacencyList[
   NearestNeighborGraph @ Tuples @ Range @ Dimensions @ #, #2] &;

vNNeighbors = Extract[#, vNNeighborPositions @ ##] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[Labeled[Style[#, 20] & @ MatrixForm @
      MapAt[Highlighted[#, Background -> Red] &, 
       MapAt[Highlighted, mat, vNNeighborPositions[mat, #]], #], 
    Grid[{{"pos:", #}, {"neighbors:", vNNeighbors[mat, #]}}], Top] & /@ 
 {{1, 1}, {1, 4}, {3, 1}, {4, 6}, {3, 5}}, 
 Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
SeedRandom[333]
mat = RandomInteger[10, {10, 15}];
poslist = RandomSample[Tuples @ Range @ Dimensions @ mat, 7];

Legended[MatrixPlot[ReplacePart[mat, 
   Join[Thread[poslist -> (ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length@poslist])], 
     Thread[vNNeighborPositions[mat, #] & /@ poslist -> Yellow],
     {{_, _} :> White}]], ImageSize -> 1 -> 40, Mesh -> All,
   Epilog ->  MapIndexed[Text[Style[#, 16, Black], #2 - .5] &, 
    Reverse /@ Transpose @ mat, {2}]], 
 Placed[SwatchLegend[(ColorData[97] /@ Range[Length @ poslist]), 
   Style[#, 14] & /@ ({Defer @ #, vNNeighbors[mat, #]} & /@ poslist), 
   LegendMarkerSize -> 20, LegendLabel -> "positions & neighbors"], Right]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The four neighbors are

```
ij=Map[loc + # &, {{0, -1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {1, 0}}]
```

Now you must check the index range:

```
DeleteCases[Map[{Max[1,Min[n,#[[1]] ]],Max[1,Min[m,#[[2]] ]]}& ,ij],loc] (* index pairs*)
Extract[mat,%] (* neighbors  *)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
nbrs[loc_?VectorQ, m_?MatrixQ] := Module[{nrows, ncols, pts},
  {nrows, ncols} = Dimensions[m];
  pts = Select[(loc + # &) /@ {{0, -1}, {0, 1}, {-1, 0}, {1, 0}},
    Between[#[[1]], {1, nrows}] && Between[#[[2]], {1, ncols}] &];
  Extract[mat, pts]
  ]
```