# First Neighbors in a DiskMatrix

Tags: list-manipulation

I have the next array:

```
DeleteCases[DiskMatrix[radius], 0, {2}]
```

And I would like to have access to each element first neighbors. How can I have access to those elements?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/162393/58370).

Answer (score 2):

```
dm = DiskMatrix[3];
nzp = Position[dm, 1];

RelationGraph[ChessboardDistance[##] == 1 &, nzp, 
 VertexCoordinates -> nzp,  
 PlotTheme -> "VintageDiagram", 
 VertexSize -> {.35, .2}, 
 ImageSize -> 1 -> 50]
```

[image]

Use `ManhattanDistance[##] == 1 &` in the first argument to get

[image]

**Note:** You can also define `nzp` as:

```
nzp = SparseArray[dm]["NonzeroPositions"];
```