# How to get the class of neighbors in a 2D periodic matrix?

Tags: matrix, convolution, index

I'm trying to analyze the spatial structure of some rectangular arrays by counting the number and class/type of neighboring points around every point in the arrays, *with periodic boundaries*.

For instance, suppose I have a $m$ x $n$ array with 5 different "types" at equal frequencies:

```
(*Spatial domain and random uniform frequency of the five "types"*)
nTypes = 5;
m = 50;
n = 100;
freq = ConstantArray[1/nTypes, nTypes];

(*Matrix with all the individuals,representing the types as distinct \
integers*)
myMatrix = RandomInteger[RandomChoice[freq -> Range[nTypes]], {m, n}];
```

We can visualize the matrix like this, just to see the distribution of colors (I add Black for the "0" values generated by `RandomInteger`):

```
colors = {0 -> Black, 1 -> Blue, 2 -> Red, 3 -> Green, 4 -> Orange, 
   5 -> Purple};
MatrixPlot[myMatrix, ColorRules -> colors]
```

[image]

The question is, how can I efficiently get a list of lists, where each sublist contains the "type" and neighborhood its corresponding {m,n} point in the matrix?

Ideally, this would be in a function like this:

```
myNeighborhoodsList=[myMatrix_,radius_,neighborhoodType_]
```

With output like this (or similar):

```
{{{neighbor1->5},...,{lastneighbor->2}},...,{{neighbor1->3},...,{lastneighbor->4}}}
```

Where each sublist is an association between the position of a neighbor and its "type".

Ideally, the function should take some arbitrary radius, and be able to use either [Moore](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/MooreNeighborhood.html) or [von Neumann](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/vonNeumannNeighborhood.html) neighborhoods (that's why I included these as arguments).

Currently I'm trying to map every {m,n} element with its corresponding neighborhood. For instance, for the `element` {m,n} and a Moore neighborhood of radius 1, with {m=5, n=6}, I'd do:

```
element = {5, 6};
{1 -> myMatrix[[element[[1]] - 1, element[[2]] - 1]], 
 2 -> myMatrix[[element[[1]], element[[2]] - 1]],
 3 -> myMatrix[[element[[1]] + 1, element[[2]] - 1]],
 4 -> myMatrix[[element[[1]] - 1, element[[2]]]],
 5 -> myMatrix[[element[[1]] + 1, element[[2]]]], 
 6 -> myMatrix[[element[[1]] - 1, element[[2]] + 1]],
 7 -> myMatrix[[element[[1]], element[[2]] + 1]],
 8 -> myMatrix[[element[[1]] + 1, element[[2]] + 1]]}
```

Giving a list in the form:

```
{1 -> 3, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 0, 4 -> 2, 5 -> 2, 6 -> 0, 7 -> 2, 8 -> 0}
```

I'm having trouble trying to generalize this to an arbitrary radius, and a different neighborhood (von Neumann, etc). I'm wondering if it's possible to use some sort of [convolution kernel](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListConvolve.html) applied to the entire matrix with periodic boundaries, which would allow us to define arbitrary neighborhoods (not just Moore/von Neumann).

Comment: This may help https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/162393/extract-four-von-neumann-neighbors-of-a-matrix-entry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this?

```
extractNeighborsNeumann[m_, r_] := {
  center -> Part[m, r + 1, r + 1],
  neighbors -> extractNeighbors[
    m,
    DiamondMatrix[r] - CenterArray[1, {2 r + 1, 2 r + 1}]
    ]
  }
extractNeighborsMoore[m_, r_] := {
  center -> Part[m, r + 1, r + 1],
  neighbors -> extractNeighbors[
    m,
    BoxMatrix[r] - CenterArray[1, {2 r + 1, 2 r + 1}]
    ]
  }
extractNeighbors[m_, mask_] := Pick[Flatten[m], Flatten[mask], 1]

partitionMap[f_, m_, r_] := Developer`PartitionMap[f, 
  m, {2 r + 1, 2 r + 1}, {1, 1}, {r + 1, r + 1}]
myNeighborhoodsList[m_, r_, "Neumann"] := 
 partitionMap[extractNeighborsNeumann[#, r] &, m, r]
myNeighborhoodsList[m_, r_, "Moore"] := 
 partitionMap[extractNeighborsMoore[#, r] &, m, r]

m = Partition[Range[9], 3];
myNeighborhoodsList[m, 1, "Moore"]

(* Out: {{{center -> 1, neighbors -> {7, 3, 2, 4}}, {center -> 2, 
   neighbors -> {8, 1, 3, 5}}, {center -> 3, 
   neighbors -> {9, 2, 1, 6}}}, {{center -> 4, 
   neighbors -> {1, 6, 5, 7}}, {center -> 5, 
   neighbors -> {2, 4, 6, 8}}, {center -> 6, 
   neighbors -> {3, 5, 4, 9}}}, {{center -> 7, 
   neighbors -> {4, 9, 8, 1}}, {center -> 8, 
   neighbors -> {5, 7, 9, 2}}, {center -> 9, 
   neighbors -> {6, 8, 7, 3}}}} *)

myNeighborhoodsList[m, 1, "Neumann"]

(* Out: {{{center -> 1, neighbors -> {9, 7, 8, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5}}, {center -> 2, 
   neighbors -> {7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6}}, {center -> 3, 
   neighbors -> {8, 9, 7, 2, 1, 5, 6, 4}}}, {{center -> 4, 
   neighbors -> {3, 1, 2, 6, 5, 9, 7, 8}}, {center -> 5, 
   neighbors -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}}, {center -> 6, 
   neighbors -> {2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 8, 9, 7}}}, {{center -> 7, 
   neighbors -> {6, 4, 5, 9, 8, 3, 1, 2}}, {center -> 8, 
   neighbors -> {4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 1, 2, 3}}, {center -> 9, 
   neighbors -> {5, 6, 4, 8, 7, 2, 3, 1}}}} *)
```

`` Developer`PartitionMap `` is [not well documented](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/Developer/ref/PartitionMap.html), also the documentation says that it has been superseded by `BlockMap`. However, a more thorough documentation of its arguments is available under [Partition](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html?q=Partition). Why not use `BlockMap`? `BlockMap` unfortunately does not support some of the arguments that we need to rely on in order to take the periodic boundaries into account.

## Neighborhoods

The neighborhoods are implemented by creating "masks" of the elements belonging to the neighborhoods. A mask is a matrix of ones and zeros, where ones are neighbors.

### Von Neumann

The Von Neumann neighborhood is implemented using `DiamondMatrix`, and `CenterArray` is used to remove the center:

```
r = 3;
m = DiamondMatrix[r] - CenterArray[1, {2 r + 1, 2 r + 1}];
m // MatrixPlot
```

[image: Output]

### Moore

The Moore neighborhood is implemented using `BoxMatrix`, and `CenterArray` is used to remove the center:

```
r = 3;
m = BoxMatrix[r] - CenterArray[1, {2 r + 1, 2 r + 1}];
MatrixPlot[m]
```

[image: Output]

### Other neighborhoods

Other neighborhoods can be constructed by combining functions such as `DiamondMatrix`, `BoxMatrix`, `CrossMatrix`, `DiskMatrix`, `CenterArray`
etc.

## Extension to get the indices of the matrix elements

It is easy to make a version of `` Developer`PartitionMap `` that also gives the index of the element it is currently mapping over. I'll illustrate it for the Moore neighborhood. Here is the `partitionMapIndexed` function:

```
partitionMapIndexed[f_, m_, r_] := MapIndexed[f,
  Partition[m, {2 r + 1, 2 r + 1}, {1, 1}, {r + 1, r + 1}],
  {2}
  ]
```

Now, we might do the following:

```
SetAttributes[myMod, Listable]
myMod[v_, max_] := If[
  v >= 1, Mod[v, max, 1],
  max - Mod[Abs[v], max]
  ]

neighborIndices[centerIndex_, width_, r_, mask_] := Pick[Flatten[Table[
    myMod[centerIndex + {i, j}, width],
    {i, -r, r},
    {j, -r, r}
    ], 1], Flatten[mask], 1]

extractNeighborsMoore[m_, idx_, width_, r_] := {
  center -> Part[m, r + 1, r + 1],
  centerIndex -> idx,
  neighbors -> extractNeighbors[
    m,
    BoxMatrix[r] - CenterArray[1, {2 r + 1, 2 r + 1}]
    ],
  neighborsIndices -> neighborIndices[
    idx,
    width,
    r,
    BoxMatrix[r] - CenterArray[1, {2 r + 1, 2 r + 1}]
    ]
  }

myNeighborhoodsList[m_, r_, "Moore"] := 
 partitionMapIndexed[extractNeighborsMoore[#, #2, Length[m], r] &, m, r]

m = Partition[Range[9], 3];
myNeighborhoodsList[m, 1, "Moore"]

(* Out: {{{center -> 1, centerIndex -> {1, 1}, 
   neighbors -> {9, 7, 8, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5}, 
   neighborsIndices -> {{3, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}, {2, 
      3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}}, {center -> 2, centerIndex -> {1, 2}, 
   neighbors -> {7, 8, 9, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6}, 
   neighborsIndices -> {{3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}, {1, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 
      1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}}}, {center -> 3, centerIndex -> {1, 3}, 
   neighbors -> {8, 9, 7, 2, 1, 5, 6, 4}, 
   neighborsIndices -> {{3, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 1}, {2, 
      2}, {2, 3}, {2, 1}}}}, {{center -> 4, centerIndex -> {2, 1}, 
   neighbors -> {3, 1, 2, 6, 5, 9, 7, 8}, 
   neighborsIndices -> {{1, 3}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 2}, {3, 
      3}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}}}, {center -> 5, centerIndex -> {2, 2}, 
   neighbors -> {1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9}, 
   neighborsIndices -> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 3}, {3, 
      1}, {3, 2}, {3, 3}}}, {center -> 6, centerIndex -> {2, 3}, 
   neighbors -> {2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 8, 9, 7}, 
   neighborsIndices -> {{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 1}, {3, 
      2}, {3, 3}, {3, 1}}}}, {{center -> 7, centerIndex -> {3, 1}, 
   neighbors -> {6, 4, 5, 9, 8, 3, 1, 2}, 
   neighborsIndices -> {{2, 3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}, {3, 3}, {3, 2}, {1, 
      3}, {1, 1}, {1, 2}}}, {center -> 8, centerIndex -> {3, 2}, 
   neighbors -> {4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 1, 2, 3}, 
   neighborsIndices -> {{2, 1}, {2, 2}, {2, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 3}, {1, 
      1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}}}, {center -> 9, centerIndex -> {3, 3}, 
   neighbors -> {5, 6, 4, 8, 7, 2, 3, 1}, 
   neighborsIndices -> {{2, 2}, {2, 3}, {2, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 1}, {1, 
      2}, {1, 3}, {1, 1}}}}} *)
```

`neighborIndices` is a new function that takes the index of the center element and produces the indices of the neighbor elements.

Comment: Very nice! A couple of questions: what part of this solution takes care of the periodic boundaries, and what does `Developer\`PartitionMap` does? (and, it seems that it has been "superseded" by `BlockMap', are they equivalent?) Thanks!

Comment: It seems that the expected number of neighbors in a Moore/von Neumann radius of 2 (or more) does not match the solution here. Maybe they are also swapped (i.e. for a Moore neighborhood of radius 2 one expects 24 neighbors, but we get only 8). The "Moore" option seems to give the Neumann neighborhoods, but undercounted (i.e. a von Neumann of radius 2 should give 12 neighbors, but it only gives 10 -when using "Moore", as I mention-).

Comment: Fixed these problems by swapping the names (Moore/Neumann) and using `DiamondMatrix` instead of `CrossMatrix` for the Neumann neighborhood. One last question, how can one extract the indexes of the neighbors around a given point? (their `Flatten` indexes, for instance).

Comment: @TumbiSapichu I've corrected the problems now, please have another look. I also made a comment about `PartitionMap`, that it takes care of the periodic boundaries using arguments documented under the `Partition` function. I'm not sure how the indexing is supposed to be done, do you mean like the index that that particular neighbor has in the full matrix? Or its index in the neighborhood?

Comment: .@C. E. thanks for the updates! For the indexing, I meant how do I retrieve the index relative to the full matrix of a particular neighbor. For instance, if some element is `{center->2, neighbors->{1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3}}`, could I get the corresponding matrix indexes of  the `{1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3}` part?  (i.e. a list `{{2,4,},{2,3},...,etc`}). Maybe even better the indexes of both `center` and `neighbors`.

Comment: The `Flatten` version of the indexing would be great, but it does not really matter. I just realized my previous comment has the unflattened version. As long as the proper indexing is retrieved.

Comment: @TumbiSapichu Have a look at my new update.

Comment: Looks great, thanks! Do you know what happens with undocumented functions in MMA over time? I'm just curious how much could one can rely on things like `Developer\`PartitionMap` in the long run (although the new function `partitionMapIndexed` doesn't rely on this, right?).

Comment: @TumbiSapichu They are not guaranteed to continue to be supported, although I would say they are likely to be. You are right that `partitionMapIndexed` does not rely on that function, and you may also note that if you replace `MapIndexed` in that function by `Map` then you get the exact equivalent of ``Developer`PartitionMap`` for matrices.

Comment: .@C. E. I think the periodic boundaries might not be captured correctly from the new functions. If we take `m = Partition[Range[16], 4]`, we see that the `neighbors` at position 1 (index `center -> 1, centerIndex -> {1, 1}`) are what we expect (`neighbors -> {16, 13, 14, 4, 2, 8, 5, 6}`), but the indexes are not: `neighborsIndices -> {{3, 3}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}, {2, 
   3}, {2, 1}, {2, 2}}` (i.e. one would expect that the neighbor with value 16 has index `{4,4}`, the lower right corner). Or maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: @TumbiSapichu yeah, that was a mistake. I think I fixed it now.